# Gebrauch von Plusquamperfekt in einem Passivsatz mit "seit"

Tags: meaning, difference, preposition, verb, tense

Warum benutzt der Autor [dieses Artikels](https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/brandenburg-fischsterben-in-der-oder-akute-krisenlage-laut-umweltminister-axel-vogel-vorbei-a-7f280be4-c0bd-493b-b8ff-37a8fe7cbad8) das Plusquamperfekt anstatt des Perfekts (oder Präteritums) im folgenden Satz?

> Seit Anfang August war aus dem deutsch-polnischen Grenzfluss
> tonnenweise toter Fisch geborgen worden.

Wäre dieser Satz in der Gegenwartsform geschrieben (also, "Seit Anfang August wird ... geborgen"), würde er bedeuten, dass zum Zeitpunkt der Veröffentlichung dieses Artikels Fische immer noch geborgen wurden, wenn ich recht verstehe.

Wäre der Satz andererseits mit dem Perfekt gebildet ("Seit Anfang August ist ... geborgen worden) oder Präteritum ("Seit Anfang August wurde ... geborgen"), würde er bedeuten, glaube ich, dass das Bergen der Fische irgendwann vor dem Zeitpunkt des Artikels  aufgehört hatte (oder zumindest etwas Interessantes inzwischen vorgekommen war).

Stimmt alles bisher? Wenn nicht, wie liege ich falsch? Wenn ja, was bedeutet der Satz wie geschrieben, d. h., mit dem Plusquamperfekt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Plusquamperfekt ergibt sich nicht aus dem angegebenen Satz selbst, sondern aus dem Zusammenhang. Der Artikel berichtet von einer Sitzung des Umweltausschusses, die in der Vergangenheit liegt und deswegen im Imperfekt steht.

Die toten Fische sind aber vorher beobachtet worden (Vorvergangenheit); um das auszudrücken, wird dann das Plusquamperfekt verwendet.

Für eine Erzählung im Präsens wird das Perfekt als Vorvergangenheit benutzt.

Comment: Danke Guidot, aber ich verstehe nicht. Nehmen wir: "Eine Sitzung des Ausschusses fand Ende August statt. Die akute Krisenlage war zu diesem Zeitpunkt vorbei. Seit Anfang August sind tote Fische geborgen worden." Ist das Perfekt im letzten Satz nicht ausreichend, um auszudrücken, dass das Bergen der Fische vor der Sitzung passiert ist? Ich verstehe natürlich, dass man normalerweise das Plusquamperfekt benutzt, wenn es um etwas vor etwas anderes in der Vergangenheit geht, aber ich hatte gedacht, dass das Wort "seit" die Situation ändern würde.

Comment: Sowohl "Eine Sitzung..." wie auch "Die akute..." sind Sätze im Präteritum. Etwas, das vor einem Ereignis, das im Präteritum geschildert wird, stattfindet, steht im Plusquamperfekt. Würde der Satz so, wie du ihn vorschlägst, dastehen, dann würden die Fische (jetzt) immer noch geborgen werden - was aber offenbar nicht der Fall ist, denn "die [...] Krisenlage war [...] vorbei".

Comment: @bakunin Danke dir auch. Ich glaube, ich verstehe langsam. Das geht anders auf Englisch, in dem wir bei "since" nur zwei Möglichkeiten haben: das Perfekt, das dem deutschen Präsens enspricht, und das Plusquamperfekt, das scheinbar sowohl dem deuschen Perfekt/Präteritum als auch dem deutschen Plusquamperfekt entspricht. Englisch fehlt also eine Unterscheidung, die im Deutschen zur Verfügung steht.